# multiple conditions in a for loop matlab

Tags: matlab, for-loop, multiple-conditions

I am trying to write a for loop with multiple conditions, for example:

```
for i=1:100 && j=1:100
    plot(i,j)
end
```

could you guys help me out please, this is my first time doing this

Comment: Sorry, I should have made this more specific, I would like it to plot the line y=x from this

Comment: please edit your question to reflect your comment.

Comment: Plotting the line `y=x` over the range `1:100` can be done with `plot(1:100)`.

Answer (score 1):

As ogzd mentioned, this is how you can plot all combinations of `i` and `j` with a nested loop.

If you are specifically interested in plotting though, you probably don't need a double loop for that. Check out:

```
hold on
for i = 1:100
    plot(i,1:100,'o')
end
```

Or even more vectorized:

```
[a b] = meshgrid(1:100,1:100)
plot(a,b,'o')
```

EDIT: maybe you are just looking for this:

```
x = 1:100;
plot(x,x) % As y = x , otherwise of course plot(x,y)
```

Comment: D'oh!! I was way overcomplicating the situation

Answer (score 1):

To plot the line y = x:

```
x = 1:100;
y = 1:100;

plot(x, y);
```

You don't need a loop at all if that's all you're trying to do.

That said, to answer your original question you cannot have multiple conditions in a for loop,  for that you want a nested for loop as @DennisJaheruddin has shown.

Comment: pretty sure this is actually what the OP was looking to do, based on the comment "I would like it to plot the line y=x from this"

Answer (score 1):

% To plot y=x, you can simply use:

```
x=1:100;
y=x;
plot(x,y)
```

However, if you want to put multiple condition in a for loop, use:

```
for x=1:100
    for y=1:100
        plot(x,y);
        continue
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **nested loops**

Try this:

```
hold on
for i=1:100
    for j=1:100
        plot(i,j)
    end
end
```

Comment: it returns one o at (100,100) an nothing else

Comment: @Chris'NamikazeKurisu'Fraser I have updated the code with the `hold on` command, now it should plot the full grid.

Comment: the hold on just returns a huge screen of blue and not the line that I am after, I tried plot(i==j) but that didn't work either (Sorry if I am sounding really stupid, this has not been a good day programming wise for me)

Comment: @Chris'NamikazeKurisu'Fraser I think i understand what you want, see my edited post

Comment: `the hold on just returns a huge screen of blue` of course it will, because you are using **all** coordinates from x=1 to 100 and y=1 to 100. You just need one loop. Close what @DennisJaheruddin suggested, but use `plot(i,i)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

For [plotting](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/plot.html)  the line `y = x` you can simply do

```
x = 1:100;
plot( x, x, '.-' );
```